# Duda href HTML problema con posición de hipervínculo

Tags: html, href

**Hola buenos dias estoy empezando a aprender HTML y tengo este problema el hipervinculo me sale al costado de la imagen y como podria hacer para dejarlo debajo del titulo H1 "Enlace para ver la temporada 7"?**

```html
    <html>
        <head>
              <title>Temporada 7</title> 
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Enlace para ver la temporada 7</h1>
            <a  target = "_blank " href ="https://www.amazon.com/-/es/gp/video/detail/B07JFGJVM1/ref=atv_dp_season_select_s7">Temporada 7</a>  
            <img src = "t7.jpg" alt= "t7"
        </body>
        
    </html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si por eso cuando lo abro en el Chrome sale al costado de la imagen el hipervínculo, puede ser porque tenga que bajarle el tamaño?

Comment: Lo mas simple es mover a la etiqueta a dentro de un p así: `<p><a  target = "_blank " href ="https://www.amazon.com/-/es/gp/video/detail/B07JFGJVM1/ref=atv_dp_season_select_s7">Temporada 7</a></p>`

Comment: ahora si ya lo pude solucionar ahora: <html>
    <head>
          <title>Temporada 7</title> 
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Enlace para ver la temporada 7</h1>
        <p><a  target = "_blank " href ="https://www.amazon.com/-/es/gp/video/detail/B07JFGJVM1/ref=atv_dp_season_select_s7">Temporada 7</p></a>  
        <img src = "t7.jpg" alt= "t7"
    </body>

    
</html>  muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Publica tu solución y considera marcarla como aceptada así los demás sabrán

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres una solución sin hacer uso de hojas de estilo debes tener en cuenta que las etiqueta `<a>` y `<img>` son [elementos inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) y por tanto están en el mismo bloque, para que estén en distintos bloques tendrás que encerrar alguno de estos en una [etiqueta  en bloque](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) como por ejemplo `<div>`:

```
<h1>Enlace para ver la temporada 7</h1>
<a  target = "_blank " href ="https://www.amazon.com/-/es/gp/video/detail/B07JFGJVM1/ref=atv_dp_season_select_s7">Temporada 7</a>
<div><img src = "t7.jpg" alt= "t7"></div>
```

Solución usando estilos(los coloque dentro de un `<div>` por gusto pero bien puedes aplicar el estilo al `<body>`):

```
<div style="display:flex;flex-flow: column;">
    <h1>Enlace para ver la temporada 7</h1>
    <a  target = "_blank " href ="https://www.amazon.com/-/es/gp/video/detail/B07JFGJVM1/ref=atv_dp_season_select_s7">Temporada 7</a>
    <img src = "t7.jpg" alt= "t7">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una de las opciones puede ser que la `img` esté dentro de la etiqueta `a`, pero en el estilo **CSS** debe ser `display: block` (en este caso el estilo le puse dentro de `img`).
Esto hace que al hacer click en el texto y o en la imagen te llevará a su enlace.

```html
    
<h1>Enlace para ver la temporada 7</h1>
<a  target = "_blank " href ="https://www.amazon.com/-/es/gp/video/detail/B07JFGJVM1/ref=atv_dp_season_select_s7">
<img src = "t7.jpg" alt= "t7" style="display:block">
Temporada 7
</a>
```

Comment: Esto hará que el url este por debajo de la imagen